# Prestashop :block layered filter disappear when using pagination

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, layered-navigation

I have a problem with block layered module, when i'm navigating between pages in filter result, the enabled filter disappear.
For example when i filter by product in stock and i have more than one page result, i tried to display the page 2, so the enabled filter will not be displayed.
Have someone met a similar problem? 
Thanks

Comment: What's your Prestashop 1.6 version and BlockLayered version?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Prestashop version 1.6.1.3, blocklayered version 2.1.3

Comment: @tarekfellah How did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem in all my prestashop installation. Thank you!